# Cannot assign string variable VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting Expected: end of statement error when trying to set my string variable (data). Below is the code, not sure why it is doing that

```
data = "{" & vbNewLine & ""First Word": {" & vbNewLine & ""Second Word": ["
```

Any idea? probably staring at me right in the face but no idea why it's doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape every double quote inside each string by using two double quotes.

Something like this:

```
data = "{" & vbNewLine & """First Word"": {" & vbNewLine & """Second Word"": ["
```